# Inability to store long list of values

Tags: asp.net

I am not able to figure out how to store long list of values (like a big text) in a dropdown list or in intellisense of search box. I see that it is displaying only half of the text but not full. How to make it appear full in the intellisense or dropdown?

Comment: What environment are you working in here? HTML? A windows application? A java frame...?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, dropdownlist control or the other similar controls are not suitable for displaying long texts. You should increase their with and it's not look pretty. My recommendation is to develope a tooltip client side script that display the full text, this would help you to show much text than the actual one.